# Can I still use RHmm package? How to install it Windows or Macs?

Tags: ios, r

I tried to install the downloaded folder as local source. It is always reporting the error:

> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘~/Downloads/RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status.

Used RHmm 2.0.3.tar.gz folder to install package RHmm on my R

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We can't really tell what's going on without seeing more of what's going on.  Can you post (in a *text* format) the full error output?